# Magento Import Configurable product With Options

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have a problem with Magento 1.9 built in import/export tool.
What I have done is:

1) I created attributes (4 of them).

2) Created attribute set.

3) Created configurable product and added some simple products to that
    configurable product.

4) Exported this product using Data Flow Profiles leaving all settings at default.

5) Modified the export file by adding multiple extra options and saved it as MS-DOS csv file.

6) Imported using Data Flow Profiles Import all products option again leaving everything at default except I have changed import number of rows value to a bigger value.

After a close examination I see that new simple products have been added to Magento store, but they are not associated with my configurable product. 
I have tried to move the line that imports the configurable product to the bottom of the csv file, but that did not help.

Has anyone else come across this problem and how did you tackle it?

Comment: Can you add that file here so I can examine.

Comment: @SunnyRathod I have learned that associating simple products with configurable products in data flow profiles is not supported, however I was able to associate them all in bulk in my control panel after I added them. Problem solved :)